# Missing Team Explorer options on home screen for TFS Git project

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I am currently workin on a visual studio online hosted project that uses git for version control and have run into a problem with the team explorer menu.

All of my collegues get this view when connecting to the project:
http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC687907.png

But on my machine, im missing the tiles/buttons and have to right click the current branch, choose manage branches and from there, select Changes/Unsynced commits to handle my code which is extremely annoying.

Im using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate for this project, but i also have VS2012 installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have `Team Foundation Version Control permissions - Manage branch`, navigate to the administration context and opening the Version Control tab.

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587.aspx

Comment: Are you sure? That setting seems to be for Solution Explorer which doesnt seem to be available for GIT repositories.

Comment: Yes sure, it's services exposed from Web services accessed by Team  Explorer